# CORS: Firefox does not send POST Request after successful OPTIONS request … works in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cross-domain, cors

I'm running into a similar issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854868/cors-firefox-does-not-send-post-request-after-successful-options-request-wo) but the best answer did not help me out. If anybody has any other ideas, I would greatly appreciate it. Here are the requests:

**Request Headers**

OPTIONS

```
Access-Control-Request-Method:  POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-annotator-auth-token,x-csrftoken
```

**Response Headers**

```
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:    http://localhost:8000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:   GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:   content-length, content-type, x-annotator-auth-token, x-requested-with, x-csrftoken
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:   true
```

It returns with a status code of 200. The actual request contains content-length, content-type, x-annotator-auth-token, and x-csrftoken but gets no status code as if it never fired. Again any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Any chance of a link to a testcase showing the problem?  That would make this pretty easy to pin down....

Answer (score 2):

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

or

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
```

and

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");  
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-Experience-API-Version,Authorization");  
//add this into your response header and it will work
```

Comment: You have to explicitly set the origin here.